# JetBrains Rider doesn't show C# WPF Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, jetbrains-ide, rider

I write an WPF application with C# in Rider.

If my program crashes it doesn't show me an exception in "Run" tab.

Only if i debug my program it shows me this unformatted output:
[image]

Is there a way to show exception output (and Console.WriteLine output) like in Java and Intellij Idea?

Comment: It's a bug. I've created an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-16602)

Comment: thanks :3
do you know how to read this string better?

Comment: Your issue doesn't describe my bug.
In my case i don't see the Stacktrace if the application throws an error. In your issue you say it does not start your app.

Comment: It's the simpliest repro when Rider doesn't show anything if application crashes on start. If fix of this bug doensn't help we'll invistigate this more

Answer (score 5):

I got it working now, but I think it is a bug in Rider.

Here is the solution:

1. Right click your Project → Properties.
2. In Tab Application → Output type, choose "Console application" instead of "Windows application".

Now you can see the output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is [a bitbonk's solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-60161/Console-output-of-WPF-Apps-is-not-redirected-to-Rider-anymore#focus=Comments-27-4869376.0-0) to [attach your app process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) to the parent console. It enables writing to console.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            AttachToParentConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("Begin init");
        }

        private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    
        /// <summary>
        ///     Redirects the console output of the current process to the parent process.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        ///     Must be called before calls to <see cref="Console.WriteLine()" />.
        /// </remarks>
        public static void AttachToParentConsole()
        {
            AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        }
    }
```

2. To write unhandled exceptions to console you should implement events [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) (a point to catch unhandled exceptions for all .NET projects) and [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception) (for WPF).